# sql:how to store the query result count directly to a infobox

Tags: php, mysql

I have an infobox to show the number of incidents:

I have a function:

```
function getStateCounts()
{
    $query = sprintf("select t1.count, t2.State_name
        from (select count(*) as count, state
            from INC_DIST_SUMMARY S
                join SHAPE_LAYERS L on L.geo_id = S.shape_geo_id
            group by state) as t1, SHAPE_LAYER_STATE_DESC as t2 
            where t1.state=t2.state");

    $count = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$count) {
        echo "<error> Invalid query " . $query . "</error>"
        die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
    }

    return $count;
}
```

and I have to store the output query result in "No of Incidents";

```
while ($item = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<item><title geoid='" . $item['GEO_ID'] . "'>" .
         $item['STATE_NAME']."(".($item['STATE_ABBR']).")" .
         "</title><description cong_dist='".$item['DIST_NAME']."'>";
    echo $item['STATE_ABBR'] . $item['DIST_NAME'] . " &lt;br/&gt";" **No of Incidents:";**
    echo $item['INC_COUNT'] . "</description>";
    echo "</item>"
```

and I have to fix this incident value at "No of Incidents":

```
while ($item = mysql_fetch_array($count, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<summary>";
    echo "<state>".$count['STATE']."</state>";
    echo "<count>".$count['COUNT']."</count>" 
    echo "</summary>";
}
```

How to display the query value in the "No of Incidents" variable?

Comment: So you want to count how many rows the query returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peform a rowCount() on a non-COUNT(*) query;

Alternatively perform a [mysql(i)_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Label the result of whichever technique you use $rowscounted and replace the

```
if (!$count) {
            echo "<error> Invalid query " . $query . "</error>";
            die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
        }

        return $count;
}
```

With:

```
if ($rowscounted == 0) {
    echo "<error> Invalid query " . $query . "</error>";
        die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
    }
else {
echo '$rowscounted states were returned by your query.'
}
```

I'm new to php so perhaps not the best answer but I've recently done a question like this myself and think this will work for you. (being a newbie, take it with a pinch of salt, oh, and a hash, if you will...)